# Distance of points from a cube in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, distance

I have the following information:

[image]

I have a set of 3d points (much more and well distributed than the ones shown in the image) and some cubes plotted. I want to find which cube each point is closest to. I had the 8 vertices of the cubes which I used to plot them.

I know I can make a plane from the vertices and find distance of the points from each of the planes and proceed in that manner. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try first evaluating the distance of each point to the centre of each cube and set a first association "points - cube".

Then you can consider the distances between the centre of the cubes: if the centres are close enough so that one cube intersects the other, perhaps the association "points - cube" should be reviewed (e. g. considering your initial approach - the planes).

Hope this helps.